# How to exclude certain #include directives from C++ stream?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have this C++ file (let's call it `main.cpp`):

```
#include <string>
#include "main.y.c"
void f(const std::string& s) {
  yy_switch_to_buffer(yy_scan_string(s.c_str()));
  yyparse();
}
```

The file depends on `main.y.c`, which has to be generated beforehand by means of `bison` util. In other words, I can't compile `main.c` file if I forget to run `bison main.y` before it. And it's perfectly OK, this is how I want it. Now I'm trying to build `.d` file from `Makefile`, using this command:

```
$ c++ -MM main.c > main.d
main.cpp:2:10: error: main.y.c: No such file or directory
```

I fail here, since `main.y.c` is not ready yet. I think that I should somehow quote my `#include` directive in the `main.c` file to make it invisible for `c++ -MM` process.

Comment: I don't know `bison` much so my question might be stupid but... including a `.c` file seems wrong. Is it really the way to work with `bison` ? Haven't you an equivalent `.h` file ?

Comment: Yes, this is how bison works if you need to wrap its result into another C++ file. By its nature bison is for C, not for C++. Thus, it is a trick to make it working in the C++ project. At least I understand it this way..

Comment: Actually I can include `.h` file, but this file is also auto-generated by `bison`.. So, replacing `.c` with `.h` won't solve the problem

Comment: com It won't solve the problem, but it might fasten the compilation time (and decrease unneeded dependency). Anyway, I thought `lex/yacc` were for `C` and `flex/bison` for `C++`. This surprises me. Have you check if `bison` can produce a `C++` output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indicate in your makefile that `main.c` depends on `main.y.c` so that it'll run the `bison` process before it tries to compile `main.c`.

As an alternative (which I think is probably not what you want to do) is that you can have your makefile pass a macro to the compiler to indicate whether or not `main.y.c` exists and use an `#if` directive to include (or not) `main.y.c`.

```
#if EXISTS_MAIN_Y_C
#include "main.y.c"
#endif
```

Comment: Won't the macro thing hide the real problem ? If the file is not generated but needed anyway, not including it will just make the real problem less obvious.

Comment: @ereOn: that why I said it's probably not a good solution. I probably shouldn't have added that...  There are times when you might want to conditionally include a header that might or might not be on a platform.  In which case you might conditionally include code that contains custom implementations of the missing platform functionality.  autoconf is commonly used to set up macros that let you do this, but you're right that's not really what this user needs here.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for a makefile. You can set the dependencies such that `main.c` depends on `main.y.c`, and `main.y.c` has a rule to build it from the bison code.